# How to read to a buffer preserving contents in the buffer?

Tags: c, linux

I need to send a file across servers, but I need to prepend a `header` in the response. I'm not sure how to tackle this because I can read the file into a buffer and send a buffer at a time with the following code:

```
while ((nread = read(in, buffer, sizeof(buffer))) > 0) {
  void *p = buffer;
  while (nread > 0) {
    int nwritten = write(csfd, p, nread);
    if (nwritten <= 0) {
      perror("error while sending the file to the client");
      close(in);
      close(csfd);
    }
    nread -= nwritten;
    p += nwritten;
  }
}
close(in);
close(csfd);
```

But since I need to send the header I need to be able to send the first chunk of data as `<HEADER>\r\n<DATA-1/33>` and subsequent writes to the socket should be like `<DATA-2/33>`, `<DATA-3/33>`, `<DATA-4/33>` and so on.

So, assuming I have a header in a `char header[] = "FOUND 43199 29-33\r\n"`, how do I get that sent in conjunction to the first chunk of data from the file?

Maybe I can read to the buffer starting at a later position in the array after I copy the header? or maybe there is some much better way?

Comment: You could indeed read starting at a later position with something like `read(buf + strlen(header), ...)`. You could also just send your header through the socket and then send your buffer.

Comment: I don't understand what's preventing you from sending the header before the buffer you want to send...

Comment: You can certainly do `size_t len = strlen(buffer); read(in, buffer + len, sizeof(buffer) - len);`

Comment: I don't understand why you can't have a bigger buffer and use your "buffer" as the payload section?

Comment: Shouldn't you exit the `write` loop if `write` fails?

Comment: @gd1 project requirements. I have to send the header and the first chunk of data in the same write to the socket.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews newbie here, if you can give a little more detail, that would be awesome.

Comment: @mimoralea : I see. Please consider that there's is no guarantee that the other end will read it with a single read(). Does it really make a difference then?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg yes sir, will fix that as well. Thanks!

Comment: @gd1 Good you point that out. Though, giving that the header is very small, like `FOUND 34556 994-33\r\n` most likely the header and some of the first chunk of data will be received together. So hopefully, (when I implement the client) I can account for most cases.

Comment: @szczurcio I'm going to give that a try. Thanks!

Comment: @mimoralea : There's no way to tell how the data will be fragmented, you should really code the client in such a way that it can potentially read one byte at a time. **TCP is not a packet protocol, it is a stream protocol that does not preserve application-defined boundaries**

Comment: Question 1: *Is* this TCP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend either a packed structure or a large buffer with a payload section:

```
+------------------------------------+  
|                                    |  
|  +----------+----------+--------+  |  
|  |  Header  |  Payload | Footer |  |  
|  +----------+----------+--------+  |  
|    transmit buffer                 |  
+------------------------------------+
```

You would send the *transmit buffer* out, but you can change the header, payload or footer without having to change the code that sends the transmit buffer.

**Edit 1: Implementation**
One method of implementation is using a structure:

```
struct Transmit_Buffer
{
  Header  m_header;
  uint8_t m_payload[PAYLOAD_CAPACITY];
  Footer  m_footer;
};
```

Another implementation is as an array of bytes (`uint8_t`):

```
uint8_t transmit_buffer[HEADER_SIZE + PAYLOAD_CAPACITY + FOOTER_SIZE];
```

And you can refer to the sections by index:

```
const unsigned int header_index = 0U;
const unsigned int payload_begin = header_index + HEADER_SIZE;
const unsigned int footer_begin = payload_begin + PAYLOAD_CAPACITY;
```

Using the structure would be:

```
Transmit_Buffer buffer;
Send_Data((uint8_t *) &buffer, sizeof(Transmit_Buffer));
```

Using the array:

```
Send_Data(&transmit_buffer[0], sizeof(transmit_buffer));
```

To change the payload, you would access only the payload section:

```
uint8_t * p_payload = &transmit_buffer[payload_begin];
```

Or

```
buffer.m_payload
```

In this design, the transmit function doesn't care what is in the buffer, it's purpose is to transmit the data.

You could add another layer that creates the header and footer sections, then transmits the data.  In this case, the payload is of no concern, as it is just plain, boring, data.

So if the header and footer are the same, you would write the payload section, then transmit the buffer.

Comment: Is this something like an array `transmit buffer` or an actual struct that includes the other parts of it? Can you give a quick code example?

Comment: @mimoralea: See my Edit 1.

Comment: If the header does not contain the payload length, then the footer will mark the end of the message and **must be escaped in the payload**, if such and ending sequence *might* be present in the payload as well by pure accident. Never, never assume your message will be delivered as a whole, TCP is a stream protocol, it **does not necessarily preserve your application-level boundaries** and `write()` cannot be used for application-level framing. The code on the client side must be designed in such a way that it can receive and parse one byte at a time.

Answer (score 2):

Just send the header and then the payload through the socket.

If you are concerned about the fact that your client will have to make two reads rather than one, and you are kind of relying on having to perform a single read, please rework your client as soon as possible, because **TCP is not a packet protocol, it is a stream protocol that does not preserve application-defined boundaries**. You should code your client in such a way that it works even if receives one byte at a time. You have to use a stateful parser, don't assume the client will be able to `read()` the entire message at once, and don't expect the sender-side boundaries to be preserved.

This implies that either your header should contain the length of the payload, or you should have a footer (but in that case, you'll have to escape such an ending sequence in the payload, which is somewhat inconvenient).

**You can't use different `write()` calls to enforce application-level framing!**